# Как узнать полное имя файла по его началу?

Tags: python

Нужны файлы ssfn8863805031775494 и ssfn8786241405251389450. Они находятся в корневой папке стима, но последние цифры после ssfn рандомные.

Как мне узнать название файла полностью?

Comment: Сделать os.listdir и в цикле проверить все файлы из списка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно также воспользоваться библиотекой `os`

Вариант для получения только имен файлов:

```
import os

path = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam'
mask = 'ssfn'
files = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, f)) and f.startswith(mask)]
```

Вариант получения полных путей к файлам

```
files = [f for f in map(lambda x: os.path.join(path, x), os.listdir(path)) if os.path.isfile(f) and os.path.basename(f).startswith(mask)]
```

Через `os.listdir(path)` получаем список содержимого папки, через `os.path.isfile(f)` проверяем, что файл, и с помощью `f.startswith(mask)` проверяем, что файл начинается с заданной маски.

Вариант с копированием файлов через `copy2`:

```
import os
from shutil import copy2

path = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam'
dest = os.getcwd()
mask = 'ssfn'
files = [f for f in map(lambda x: os.path.join(path, x), os.listdir(path)) if os.path.isfile(f) and os.path.basename(f).startswith(mask)]
for f in files:
    copy2(src=f, dst=dest)
```

Comment: @MaxU не работает 2ой способ, вот скриншот https://screen.doxy.wtf/screenshot/ihackdym/odvI2GJv (если что то это upload systems, почитайте про этот хостинг), 1вый способ работает, но как мне их скопировать через shutil.copy2

Comment: Обновил. Для проверки на то, что это файл нужно использоваться полный путь. Мой вариант сделан был для рабочей директории. Теперь должно работать. Добавил `os.path.join(path, f)` в `os.path.isfile()`

Comment: Я сделал, работает https://screen.doxy.wtf/screenshot/ihackdym/hRxtyDLt, но как мне их по очереди скопировать через shutil.copy2 (Ps. их всегда 2, но с разными цифрами после ssnf)

Comment: Добавил в пост ниже вариант реализации

Comment: @TheHYLIGAN, https://stackoverflow.com/a/18372078/5741205

Answer (score 5):

воспользуйтесь `pathlib`:

```
from pathlib import Path

steam_dir = Path("/path/to/steam")

ssfn_files = list(steam_dir.glob("ssfn*"))
```

Comment: MaxU, и он будет именно их искать?

Comment: @TheHYLIGAN, да, если правильно пропишите путь до "корневой папки стима"

Comment: он у меня есть, сейчас проверю напишу результат